# Transforming Alamofire response when using Codable and Combine

Tags: swift, alamofire, combine

I want to use Alamofire to query my backend, encode the response using Alamofire's built-in Codable parsing and then publish an extract from the resulting Struct to be consumed by the caller of my API class.  Say I have some JSON data from my backend (simplified, but shows the structure):

```
{
    "total": 123,
    "results": [
        {"foo" : "bar"},
        {"foo" : "baz"}
    ]
}
```

and the associated `Codable` Structs

```
struct MyServerData: Codable {
    let total: Int
    let results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let foo: String
}
```

I can get, parse, publish, and subscribe all fine with the following:

```swift
func myAPI() -> DataResponsePublisher<MyServerData> {
    return AF.request("https://backend/path")
        .validate()
        .publishDecodable(type: MyServerData.self)
}

myAPI()
    .sink { response in /* Do stuff, e.g. update @State */ }
```

What I'd like to do is to publish just the `[Result]` array.  What's the correct approach to this?  Should I use `.responseDecodable()` and create a new publisher (somehow - `.map()`?) that returns a `[Result].publisher`?

While I think I understand the reactive/stream based principles my Combine-fu is still weak and I don't have a clear handle on the transformation of one publisher into another (I'm guessing?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't use Combine, but there are `map`, and I guess that it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using Combine API like `map`, Alamofire offers two publishers on `DataResponsePublisher` itself.

`.result()` extracts the `Result` from the `DataResponse` and creates an `AnyPublisher<Result<Value, AFError>, Never>`.

`.value()` extracts the `Value` from the `DataResponse` and creates a failable publisher, `AnyPublisher<Value, AFError>`.

So depending on what kind of error handling you want, this could be as simple as:

```swift
...
  .publishDecodable(...)
  .value()
  .map(\.results)
```

Comment: I'd so nearly got there; you helped me over the line, thanks!  Having had a bit more of a play the difference between `value()` and `result()` seems to be that `.result()` allows you to handle errors at either end of the pub-sub while `value()` leans heavily towards handling them as part of the pub chain.  Might be wrong, but I've managed to climb over the current hurdle with the help of the above, a success/failure switch and a trailing `.eraseToAnyPublisher()`.

Comment: Yeah, it just depends on which style you like. I usually go for `Result`s as I don't like handling errors in streams.